# How to upload files to google drive using java-Google Docs Api?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, google-docs-api

Already I used older version of the API to upload files to Google docs but now the API version is revised, so I couldn't upload.

Previously I used these lines for authorization:

```
DocsService service = new DocsService("MyDocumentsListIntegration-v1");
    service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

But now it is giving this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at sample.main(sample.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are missing one of the external dependencies, mail.jar, which is part of Sun's JavaMail API.

Check this page for instructions on how to get it as well as all other external dependencies: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/java_client_lib